# regex: How do I match for anything BUT a given value as well as another condition

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that I'm regex matching for a list of matching values in part of the string, which works fine, but I want to further restrict the regex to also match a different part of the string for anything BUT a given value.

The regex I'm using for the first part that work is:

```
ControlListOptions.match(new RegExp("<option scriptstepdatatypeid='(" + enumControlType.GenericList + "|" + enumControlType.SalutationList + "|" + enumControlType.StateList + "|" + enumControlType.StreetTypeList + ")' stepid='" + stepid + "' .*?>(.*?)<\/option>","gi"))
```

However, I want to restrict it to data that has a value attribute of anything BUT a given value.

I tried by using something like:

```
ControlListOptions.match(new RegExp("<option scriptstepdatatypeid='(" + enumControlType.GenericList + "|" + enumControlType.SalutationList + "|" + enumControlType.StateList + "|" + enumControlType.StreetTypeList + ")' stepid='" + stepid + "' value='(.(?!4642))*'>(.*?)<\/option>","gi"))
```

But that gives me even more matches than the first regex, so that seems to widen the matching criteria somehow.

The ControlListOptions variable has the following value:

```
<option scriptstepdatatypeid='28' stepid='19' value='342'>19 : First Step : 342 : First Field</option><option scriptstepdatatypeid='20' stepid='19' value='1299'>19 : First Step : 1299 : On a scale of 1 to 10, how satisfied are you with our service?[1,10,1,10]</option><option scriptstepdatatypeid='1' stepid='19' value='1300'>19 : First Step : 1300 : Yes No</option><option scriptstepdatatypeid='23' stepid='19' value='1301'>19 : First Step : 1301 : Address</option><option scriptstepdatatypeid='5' stepid='19' value='4641'>19 : First Step : 4641 : Parent List[1,2,3,1140,4,5,61,64]</option><option scriptstepdatatypeid='5' stepid='19' value='4642'>19 : First Step : 4642 : Generic List 1</option><option scriptstepdatatypeid='3' stepid='19' value='4643'>19 : First Step : 4643 : Text Area</option><option scriptstepdatatypeid='25' stepid='19' value='4644'>19 : First Step : 4644 : Numeric</option><option scriptstepdatatypeid='26' stepid='19' value='4645'>19 : First Step : 4645 : List Builder</option><option scriptstepdatatypeid='5' stepid='19' value='4646'>19 : First Step : 4646 : List 1[A,B,C,D,E,F]</option><option scriptstepdatatypeid='27' stepid='19' value='4647'>19 : First Step : 4647 : DateTime</option><option scriptstepdatatypeid='6' stepid='19' value='4648'>19 : First Step : 4648 : Date</option><option scriptstepdatatypeid='14' stepid='19' value='4649'>19 : First Step : 4649 : Phone number</option><option scriptstepdatatypeid='29' stepid='19' value='4650'>19 : First Step : 4650 : Grid</option><option scriptstepdatatypeid='2' stepid='19' value='4651'>19 : First Step : 4651 : Client Company ID</option><option scriptstepdatatypeid='2' stepid='21' value='341'>21 : Enter Data : 341 : Test Field</option><option scriptstepdatatypeid='24' stepid='27' value='1988'>27 : Add Structure : 1988 : Choose Structure(s)</option><option scriptstepdatatypeid='2' stepid='1405' value='1302'>1405 : Lounge : 1302 : Option Field</option><option scriptstepdatatypeid='2' stepid='1406' value='1303'>1406 : Kitchen : 1303 : Option Field</option><option scriptstepdatatypeid='2' stepid='1407' value='1304'>1407 : Bathroom : 1304 : Option Field</option><option scriptstepdatatypeid='2' stepid='1409' value='1305'>1409 : Add Structure or Continue : 1305 : Estimated Cost</option><option scriptstepdatatypeid='1' stepid='1409' value='1306'>1409 : Add Structure or Continue : 1306 : Walls</option><option scriptstepdatatypeid='21' stepid='1410' value='1161'>1410 : Dropout Step : 1161 : PDF Link</option><option scriptstepdatatypeid='2' stepid='1412' value='1298'>1412 : Don't enter data : 1298 : Skipped Field</option>
```

And I would expect the following as the result:

```
["<option scriptstepdatatypeid='5' stepid='19' value='4641'>19 : First Step : 4641 : Parent List[1,2,3,1140,4,5,61,64]</option>", "<option scriptstepdatatypeid='5' stepid='19' value='4646'>19 : First Step : 4646 : List 1[A,B,C,D,E,F]</option>"]
```

Any ideas?

UPDATE:
I was pretty sure that the answer supplied of using value='(?!4642).*' had worked, but I've since found that it is matching too many values.  The regex I'm using now ends up as:

```
<option scriptstepdatatypeid='5|8|9|16' stepid='19' value='(?!4642).*'>(.*?)</option>
```

and the matches that it is returning are:

```
["<option scriptstepdatatypeid='5' stepid='19' value='4641'>19 : First Step : 4641 : Parent List[1,2,3,1140,4,5,61,64]</option><option scriptstepdatatypeid='5' stepid='19' value='4642'>19 : First Step : 4642 : Generic List 1</option><option scriptstepdatatypeid='3' stepid='19' value='4643'>19 : First Step : 4643 : Text Area</option><option scriptstepdatatypeid='25' stepid='19' value='4644'>19 : First Step : 4644 : Numeric</option><option scriptstepdatatypeid='26' stepid='19' value='4645'>19 : First Step : 4645 : List Builder</option><option scriptstepdatatypeid='5' stepid='19' value='4646'>19 : First Step : 4646 : List 1[A,B,C,D,E,F]</option><option scriptstepdatatypeid='27' stepid='19' value='4647'>19 : First Step : 4647 : DateTime</option><option scriptstepdatatypeid='6' stepid='19' value='4648'>19 : First Step : 4648 : Date</option><option scriptstepdatatypeid='14' stepid='19' value='4649'>19 : First Step : 4649 : Phone number</option><option scriptstepdatatypeid='29' stepid='19' value='4650'>19 : First Step : 4650 : Grid</option><option scriptstepdatatypeid='2' stepid='19' value='4651'>19 : First Step : 4651 : Client Company ID</option><option scriptstepdatatypeid='2' stepid='21' value='341'>21 : Enter Data : 341 : Test Field</option><option scriptstepdatatypeid='24' stepid='27' value='1988'>27 : Add Structure : 1988 : Choose Structure(s)</option><option scriptstepdatatypeid='2' stepid='1405' value='1302'>1405 : Lounge : 1302 : Option Field</option><option scriptstepdatatypeid='2' stepid='1406' value='1303'>1406 : Kitchen : 1303 : Option Field</option><option scriptstepdatatypeid='2' stepid='1407' value='1304'>1407 : Bathroom : 1304 : Option Field</option><option scriptstepdatatypeid='2' stepid='1409' value='1305'>1409 : Add Structure or Continue : 1305 : Estimated Cost</option><option scriptstepdatatypeid='1' stepid='1409' value='1306'>1409 : Add Structure or Continue : 1306 : Walls</option><option scriptstepdatatypeid='21' stepid='1410' value='1161'>1410 : Dropout Step : 1161 : PDF Link</option><option scriptstepdatatypeid='2' stepid='1412' value='1298'>1412 : Don't enter data : 1298 : Skipped Field</option>"]
```

Comment: I just noticed that the second regex seems to be doing a match for 4642, where I need it to be doing a match for anything BUT 4642, so I need that bit fixed, but it still doesn't explain why the criteia seems to have been widened.

Comment: First off, it seems that if you want a quote not followed by 4642, you need `(?!4642)`, whereas at the moment you have the quote `'` then a dot `.` then the value to exclude.

Comment: What do you mean by `.*?`. Match wildcard 0-many times optionally (redundant question mark)? Or does it mean match wildcard 0-many times followed by a matching a question mark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your requirement correctly, I'd recommend using a negative lookahead - `stepid='(?!step3).*'` (match every step except "step3")

E.g.
For the following samples:

```
<option scriptstepdatatypeid='one' stepid='step1' att2='foo' >barbarbar</option>
<option scriptstepdatatypeid='two' stepid='step2' att2='foo' >barbarbar</option>
<option scriptstepdatatypeid='three' stepid='step3' att2='foo' >barbarbar</option>
<option scriptstepdatatypeid='four' stepid='step4' att2='foo' >barbarbar</option>
```

The follow regex matches all steps except "step3":

```
<option scriptstepdatatypeid='(one|two|three|four)' stepid='(?!step3).*' .*?>(.*?)</option>
```

Test it out here -> http://regexpal.com

Comment: I was wanting a match on a particular value attribute instead of a stepid attribute, but your pattern of (?!step3).* was enough to get me going with the value attribute - thanks !

Comment: Brilliant! Sorry you did mention that you wanted it for value not step, my bad - but alls well that ends well.

Comment: Actually, When I marked as the answer, I just tried it in its basic form in regexpal and it seemed fine, however, when I plug it into my code, I get more matches than I should.  The actual regex ends up being <option scriptstepdatatypeid='5|8|9|16' stepid='19' value='(?!4642).*'>(.*?)</option>, which matches too many.

Comment: Can you give me an example of what it's matching, that it shouldn't be?

Comment: Updated question so I could fit all the data you need in.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise you wanted all on one line (once again, try http://regexpal.com). The problem is your `.*` wildcards match everything! Try excluding xml brackets, something like this should fix it for you. `<option scriptstepdatatypeid='(5|8|9|16)' stepid='19' value='(?!4642)[^>]*'>([^<]*?)</option>`